# how to declare a template class as a friend in c++

Tags: c++

I wana know if we can make a partial specialized class as a friend class.

```
template< class A, class B >
class AB{};

class C;

template < class B >
class AB< C, B >{};

class D{
     template< class E > friend class AB< D, E >;
}
```

How to achieve the above.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear: there is no partial specialization in your code and you have reused class names as template argument names, making it unclear what you intended to refer to.

Comment: Your syntax of that partial specialization is wrong... Do you know how to write partial specializations? No offence, but it seems like one of those questions where someone has read something on the internet about friends and partial specializations and then quickly jumps to SO to try and get some reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not allowed by the C++ Standard (§14.5.3/9):

> Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations. [Example:

```
template<class T> class A { };
class X {
    template <class T> friend class A<T*>;   //error
};
```

> --end example]

So basically, you can either make all instantiations of `AB` friend of `D` or only one particular instantiation. [This IBM page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_8.5.1/com.ibm.tpf.toolkit.compilers.doc/ref/langref_zos/clrc13cplr042.htm#HDRCPLR042) describes the different relationships that can be achieved when it comes to friends and templates: "one-to-one", "one-to-many", "many-to-one" and "many-to-many" (but not "one-to-some" as you asked).

Comment: How to make all instantiations of `AB` friend of `D`?

Comment: @balki: `class D { template <typename A, typename B> friend class AB; };`

Answer (score 1):

see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239435/595859), thanks to [Drew Dormann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16287/drew-dormann)

```
template <class T, class C>
class proxy {
   friend C;
```

It worked for me.